# Get selected link tag

Tags: javascript, dom, selection

Here is HTML:

```
<p>The <a href="#">link</a> in text</p>
```

and here is an JavaScript code:

```
s = window.getSelection();
console.log(s.anchorNode.data,'||',s.baseNode.data,'||',s.focusNode.data);
```

When you select the "link" text and run that JS code it returns different values in different browsers: select node, previous or next node. It depends not just on browser but on the direction of selecting (moving cursor).

How can I select exactly selected link? I need to get the url of it.